# Working with Sticky Footer(sub-footer and main-footer bottom) using jquery only

Tags: jquery, css

Actually, I have two footers with dynamic content.That why I am using jquery to make sub-footer and main-footer sticky.
Now footer sticky is working, but on window resize, the height of main-footer increasing. Please see script. I think, I have issue with script. I have added script at bottom of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Sticky Footer Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;

}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
}


.footer-bottom{
padding:3px 0;
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; 
background-color:green; 
text-align:center; 
width:100%;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="page-body">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!--[ container ] -->
  <div class="container">
    content here
  </div>

  <!--[ footer ] -->
  <div class="footer">
      <p>Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>

<div class="footer-bottom">
      <p>footer Bottom</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      function sizing(){
      var completeFooter = $(".footer").height() + $(".footer-bottom").height();
$(".footer").css("height", completeFooter);
$(".page-body").css("margin-bottom", completeFooter);
}
$(document).ready(sizing);
$(window).resize(sizing);
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not remove this line `$(window).resize(sizing);`?

Comment: @Shadow Fiend, Same issue, with and without this line!

Comment: look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37652/).. i just remove that resize.. and its not growing anymore..

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT based on comment:**

- Remove the JS altogether and add the following CSS property to your dynamic footer:

`bottom: 46px;` --> your static footer's height

**[Resizable working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yso6fqfd/7/)**

Snippet below:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:46px;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-bottom {
  padding: 3px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body class="page-body">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--[ container ] -->
  <div class="container">
    content here
  </div>
  <!--[ footer ] -->
  <div class="footer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste neque deserunt alias, hic incidunt sequi reiciendis, quis nobis accusantium, quod iure, ipsum soluta architecto maxime quas veritatis sint animi repellat!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-bottom">
    <p>footer Bottom</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: please add more content in footer paragraph tag. On resize window, main footer will hide behind footer bottom. But when you will refresh page at same window size, footer will work fine.  See screen on window resize: https://imgur.com/a/bnvRE, not working fine, but when on page refresh: https://imgur.com/a/bnvRE (working fine).